# Доступ к сайту Open Server по IP

Tags: openserver, alias

Подскажите пожалуйста, уже всю голову сломал, и настраивал раньше и работало все, а сейчас хоть ты тресни не могу понять что не так.

Первая картинка ( https://ibb.co/Ydx2Rgj )- настройка доступа со всех адресов

Вторая картинка ( https://ibb.co/1R7cKvL ) - локальный адрес указывает на алиас который настроен на корневой каталог сайта (но поскольку это Yii2 то там нету index файла и показывает просто каталоги, если вручную щелкнуть на каталог Web, то сайт загружается.

Третья картинка ( https://ibb.co/rc9Y8xP ) - локальный адрес указывает на алиас который настроен на корневой каталог сайта + каталог web в котором стартовый index.php - но тут вылетает ошибка "Упс как вы сюда попали"

Четвертая картинка ( https://ibb.co/JKzjLBP ) - настройки алиасов, о которых я писал выше

В окне браузера естественно набираю просто IP адрес, который на картинках.

Помогите ради бога разобраться, как сделать так чтобы работало при той настройке что на третьей картинке. Оно у меня работало, а сейчас голова кругом и никак сообразить не могу что не так. Спасибо огромное, знаю что наверняка расписано разъяснено, но не нашел, а делаю вроде правильно.

Answer (score 0):

По какой-то причине ваша локальная папка с yii недоступна по домену. Причина может быть в конфигурации virtual host, htaccess и др.

Если вышло упс на странице, значит сервер http показывает содержимое папки - OSPanel\modules\system\html\default.